# Retrieve subscription data in one component using graphql?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am using graphql subscriptions to update my UI. Currently I am needing 2 components to update the data, as I am unsure of another way of accessing the `subscribeToMore` in the `componentDidMount` block. Is it possible to do all this in one component?

My code looks like this:

**App.js**

```
const App = () => (
  <Query query={GET_MESSAGES}>
    {({ data, loading, subscribeToMore }) => {
      if (!data) {
        return null;
      }

      if (loading) {
        return <span>Loading ...</span>;
      }

      return (
        <Messages
          messages={data.messages}
          subscribeToMore={subscribeToMore}
        />
      );
    }}
  </Query>
);
```

**Messages.js**

```
class Messages extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.subscribeToMore({
      document: MESSAGE_CREATED,
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
        if (!subscriptionData.data) return prev;

        return {
          messages: [
            ...prev.messages,
            subscriptionData.data.messageCreated,
          ],
        };
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.messages.map(message => (
          <li key={message.id}>{message.content}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```